# Calculate dy/dx given implicit equation

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I need help with this one. Calculate  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ for:

a)$\ln(xyz)+x^2y^2z^2=0$
b)$x^2yz+yz^2+x^2z^2-3=0$
c)$\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{y+z}+\sqrt{z+x}+3=0$
d)$\sin(xy)+\cos(xy)+\tan(xy)+xyz=0$

Please post the full solution.

Comment: I don't know what to do, I don't know what  I am supposed to do...

Comment: Have you taken a look in your textbook? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17164/159845

Comment: @Sonic: Basically you assume that the equation defines implicitly $z$ as a function $x$ and $y$, that is, $z=f(x,y)$, and then consider this fact and differentiate each equation w.r. to $x$ and $y$, respectively.

Comment: yes, but we didn't discuss this type of exercises, if that would be the case I wouldn't be here , begging for help

Comment: Can someone solve one of them, to have an example to work with ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone solve one of them, to have an example to work with ?

I'll get you started with *one*; try to fill in the details and use the technique on the other ones.

> I need help with this one. Calculate  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ for:
>   a)$\ln(xyz)+x^2y^2z^2=0$

You assume $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, that is: $z(x,y)$. You need to take this into account when taking (partial) derivatives with respect to $x$ (or $y$), don't forget the *chain rule*!

I'll do the derivative with respect to $x$; the two terms separately as a preparation:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ln\left(xyz\right) = \frac{1}{xyz}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(xyz\right) = 
\frac{1}{xyz}y\left(x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+z\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\right)
= \frac{x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+z}{xz}$$
and:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2y^2z^2\right) = y^2\left( z^2\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x}+x^2\frac{\partial z^2}{\partial x} \right)= y^2\left( 2xz^2+2x^2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)$$
So combined:
$$ \frac{x\color{blue}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}+z}{xz}+y^2\left( 2xz^2+2x^2z\color{blue}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}} \right)=0$$
Now you can simplify and rearrange a bit; this is an equation you can solve for $\color{blue}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}$.

Differentiate with respect to $y$ to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add that in general for a function $F(x, y, z(x, y)) = 0$ we have that:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 0 = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$

If $z$ is a function of $x, y$ but they themselves are not functions of each other, we have $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$, and so really what we have is:

$$0 = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$, or $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}$$

That's known as implicit differentiation. I'd suggest you look up Implicit Function Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $\ln(xyz)+x^2y^2z^2=0$ w.r. to $x$ (in this case keep $y$ as a constant) gives $\displaystyle\frac{y(z+xz_x)}{xyz}+y^2(2xz^2+2x^2z_x)=0\Longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle\frac{z+xz_x}{xz}+y^2(2xz^2+2x^2zz_x)=0$. Solve this eqution for $z_x$. For $z_y$ you will differntiate with respect to $y$ and this time keep $x$ as a constant.